# Using Enterprise Architect Java API to connect to running instance of EA

Tags: java, enterprise-architect

We are doing some custom reports on data in EA repository - that is we take the data directly from repository database. Problem is, that we also need to export the diagrams tied to specified elements into separate files - I am experimenting with Java API to do that. What I would like to know is whether I can use the api to connect to the currently running instance of EA, or if I need to start a new instance (which would slow things down notably).

Or is there other way to achieve that goal? I am new to EA automation interface, so I would appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be possible using JACOB and this hack:

Java:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import org.sparx.App;
import com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent;

public class TestJava {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ActiveXComponent c=ActiveXComponent.connectToActiveInstance ("EA.App");
    Constructor<?> appConstructor=Class.forName("org.sparx.App").getDeclaredConstructor(long.class);
    appConstructor.setAccessible(true);
    App app=(App)appConstructor.newInstance(c.m_pDispatch);
    app.GetRepository().GetConnectionString();
    System.out.println(app.GetRepository().GetPackageByGuid("{9C9D301B-B54D-44fb-898A-0412497D39AA}").GetName());
}

}
```

Groovy:

```
import org.sparx.App
import com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent

ActiveXComponent c=ActiveXComponent.connectToActiveInstance ("EA.App")
println c.m_pDispatch
App app=new App(c.m_pDispatch);
println app.GetRepository().GetConnectionString()
println app.GetRepository().GetPackageByGuid("{9C9D301B-B54D-44fb-898A-0412497D39AA}").GetName()
```

Answer (score 1):

With .Net you can connect to the running instance using `System.Runtime.InteropServices` I'm not sure if there's a Java equivalent to the `Marshal.getActiveObject()`

This is the code from the [repository wrapper](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-Add-in-Framework/blob/master/EAAddinFramework/EAWrappers/Model.cs) in my [EA Addin Framework](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-Add-in-Framework) that connects to the currently running instance.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
/// Creates a model connecting to the first running instance of EA
public Model(){
  object obj = Marshal.GetActiveObject("EA.App");
  global::EA.App eaApp = obj as global::EA.App;
  this.initialize(eaApp.Repository);
}
```

In case you have multiple running instances then it seems to connect to the first one opened.

Comment: Thanks, you can definitely do that with dotnet (that can be used to write plugins for ea) and we are currently doing the same thing with VisualBasic 
`Dim EAApp :
 Set EAApp = GetObject(, "EA.App")`
But I dont know of any way to do it with java

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to connect to a running instance of the EA client in the EA API. EA's design is client/server (where the server is a database), so there wouldn't be much point.

However, the automation interface is also available from within EA using EA's scripting engine. Same API, supports VBScript, JavaScript and JScript.

Combining the two tasks you mention -- creating a report and exporting diagrams to files -- can be done if you're using the DocumentGenerator class in the API. In itself that can't export any files, but if you're using it that implies that you are traversing the model structure yourself instead of letting EA's built-in document generation facilities do that for you, and you could easily add some diagram-to-file exports to that code.

Comment: As @geert-bellekens wrote, there is a way to do it. We do it with VBscript, where you can actually see the diagrams get opened in running instance of EA. But i dont know of a way to do this with java

Comment: The question was how to use EA's API to connect to a running instance, and you can't. Neither the Java version nor the COM version has a call for this. You can access Windows' running object table using the Windows API in any number of languages.

Comment: I guess you are right, my question was not exact. But it means you can use this approach to connect from java program? I am sorry if my questions sound a bit dumb, i am quite green to EA and programming as well:)